# Lyx advanced search and replace not handling math mode

Tags: math-mode, lyx, find

I am trying to update my mathematical notation throughout an entire document using Lyx's advanced search and replace feature. The program is able to correctly identify instances of a certain notation. However, rather than replacing them with the desired result, it is deleting everything within the math box.

When working with text, the advanced S&R feature works fine for me. Any help much appreciated!

Steps to reproduce (see attached images also):

1. In an empty document, create a numbered formula, and insert an arbitrary character (say, the letter a).
2. Enter advanced search and replace (ctrl+shift+f), and insert a math box (ctrl+shift+m) in the 'find' section. Insert the letter a in this math box.
3. In the 'replace' section, create another math box, and insert the letter b.
4. Click 'find next' and then 'replace'.
5. Observe that the numbered formula inserted in Step 1 is now empty (the letter a has been deleted).

Using Windows 10 with Lyx 2.3.7.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's a chance this is fixed in the 2.4.0 development version. I don't recommend trying it, but the final 2.4.0 should be released in a few weeks. There's been some improvements to Advanced Find, although it is a tricky beast.

Comment: no worries, I will wait for the final 2.4.0 release in that case :) cheers